# What does mount -uw / do exactly

Tags: macos, terminal, mount

Quick question, out of curiosity:

What exactly does the -u option in `mount -uw /` do exactly?

I know this mounts the read-only file system in catalina and makes it writable with the `-w`.

**But what does the `-u` do exactly?**

I can't find this option under the mount options in the docs.
There is the `-U`  uuid option:

> **-U uuid**
>
> Mount the partition that has the specified uuid. These two options
> require the file /proc/partitions (present since Linux 2.1.116) to
> exist.

But not the lower-case option.

I hope someone can help me out here.

Comment: Take a look at https://ss64.com/osx/mount.html

Answer (score 0):

(Can't comment so answering my own question.)

Philippe's comment hold the answer. Thank you Philippe

Comment: You should add the answer here then :)

Comment: Also, I'm fairly sure you can leave comments on your own questions, or in your case, everywhere.

Comment: You are right, thanks. Next time I will open my eyes!